# Installing SharePoint 2003 on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, sharepoint-2003

Please don't ask why (ok you can ask), but I would like to (and I use the words like to lightly), install SharePoint Portal Server 2003 on my Windows XP SP3 machine natively (network policy prevents virtual machines).

I am familiar with installing MOSS and SP2010 on Windows 7 and Windows Vista, but is this possible for 2003?

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint 2003 flat out refuses to install on a client operating system.  It only works on Windows Server-based systems, and there is no known way to convince it otherwise.  The typical work-around is to put Windows Server on a VM, but since that's not an option for you I think you're out of luck.

Comment: Actually, SP2010 is supported to run on Windows 7, and there is a nice tutorial that allows you to install WSS 3.0 (and MOSS) on Windows Vista and 7. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx), (http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2008/05/21/how-to-install-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0-sp1-on-vista-x64-x86.aspx)

Comment: I am looking for something similar for sharepoint 2003 and windows xp.